# How are randomly created UUIDs compared?

Tags: java, uuid

Let's say i have below code

```
UUID u1 = UUID.randomUUID();

UUID u2 = UUID.randomUUID();
```

Am I guaranteed that u2 will always be greater than u1 as u2 was later ?

(i.e) u2.compareTo(u1) will it always be 1 ?

Comment: Eh, of course not. What is your understanding of the word 'random'?

Comment: How do you define "greater"? The idea of UUIDs is to be (most likely) be unique over time and space. That definition doesn't mention ordering though. So when you create two random UUIDs, whats the point of asking about their order? In other words: what is the problem that you think you can solve with answers to this question?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing in the documentation (see [Oracle UUID javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)) which guarentees that. So I believe you can't expect your assumption to hold.

Answer (score 3):

No.
UUID.randomUUID() will not guarantee any ordering.

This is also something you could've tested yourself extremely easily with something like the following:

```
UUID previousUuid = UUID.randomUUID();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    System.out.println(uuid.compareTo(previousUuid));
    previousUuid = uuid;
}
```

Comment: The 'help' is however useless. Such a loop could by chance run for years and always producing increasing UUIDs without confirming or rejecting any assumptions. A naive test case like this is not suitable for testing random behaviour.

Comment: Formally, you're of course correct @jarnbjo. However, in reality, I'd expect the code snippet above to show a list of only 1:s or only -1:s less than one time in a thousand, and seeing is believing. If you get only 1:s or only -1:s, the code proves nothing, but if you get both, you know that UUID.randomUUID() will not, under all circumstances, produce UUID:s that are strictly ordered.